# can't get Windows Explorer file content search to work right

Tags: windows, visual-studio

Windows Explorer fails to find string "WAZAT" is in a .htm file in the directory
"C:\WindRiver3.3\workspace\DaVinci_Control_System".

This is on Windows Vista.  But I have had trouble with Windows Explorer file search on all versions of Windows I've encountered after Windows-XP, on different computers at my home office and on all client workstations.

What is the secret???   I type "WAZAT" in the "Search " texbox in the upper right,
it doesn't find it in the filenames so I click "Search again in:  File Contents"
it finds it in only one file ( a .js file), and fails to find it in .htm files.

Comment: how is this related to visual studio? Are you using Visual Studio to search?

Comment: I'm developing in Visual Studio, and need to often search contents of source files, and thought other developers might have solution to searching with Windows Explorer.

Comment: Searching in *.htm files only searches text content (innerText). It doesn't search script or tags.

Answer (score 2):

I've always found Windows' native search capabilities somehow limited.

I'd suggest you look at the [File Content Finder](https://geosystemsdev.com/products/file-content-finder/) app on the [Windows app store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/p/file-content-finder/9mzc4sk6j6bp) (disclaimer - I'm its developer). It's specifically designed for searching file contents without indexing. It supports all major file formats - pdf, doc(x), xls(x), pptx, and others. It can even search scanned documents.

It's also available for Mac on the [Apple Store](https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/file-content-finder/id1448621435).